# Eloquent sub query got changed in derived query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent query where I join some tables together then apply different filters on that query, but after one filter, the original sub query got modified with the first filter in other filter.

this is the original query:

```
$circle = DB::table('circles')
            ->joinSub($member, 'member', function ($join) {
                $join->on('circles.id', '=', 'member.circle_id');
            })->joinSub($place, 'place', function ($join) {
                $join->on('circles.place_id', '=', 'place.placeID');
            })->joinSub($dep, 'dep', function ($join) {
                $join->on('department_id', '=', 'depID');
            })->where('use_classification', UseClassificationEnum::USES)
            ->select('id', 'circle_name', 'circle_code', 'department_name', 'place_name', 'numMem', 'leader');
```

then apply different filters

```
$current_circle = session('circle.id');
$circle_active = $circle->where('id', $current_circle)->first();
$circle_other = $circle->where('id', '<>', $current_circle)->get();
```

In `$circle_other` query, the original `$circle` was included with `where('id', $current_circle)` so it results nothing.

If I put the `$circle_active` and `$circle_other` in reverse order, then the later will result nothing.

I don't want to repeat the query just to apply different filters.
Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Comment: how you identified which filter is apply ?

Comment: @pal I use all of them in my controller function, they will go to different part of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of Laravel Query Builder source from [Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L596).

`where()` builds a query in the instance of `$circle` on your `$circle_active` query hence it's reflected in `$circle_other`.

What you can do in this situation is to create a helper like this.

```php
public static function buildCircleQuery() {
   return DB::table('circles')
            ->joinSub($member, 'member', function ($join) {
                $join->on('circles.id', '=', 'member.circle_id');
            })->joinSub($place, 'place', function ($join) {
                $join->on('circles.place_id', '=', 'place.placeID');
            })->joinSub($dep, 'dep', function ($join) {
                $join->on('department_id', '=', 'depID');
            })->where('use_classification', UseClassificationEnum::USES)
            ->select('id', 'circle_name', 'circle_code', 'department_name', 
    'place_name', 'numMem', 'leader');
}
```

Then you can do this

```php
// Note that Helper:: is based on your helper class name
$circle_active = Helper::buildCircleQuery()->where('id', $current_circle)->first();
$circle_other = Helper::buildCircleQuery()->where('id', '<>', $current_circle)->get();
```

Comment: You can also clone the query: `$circle_active = (clone $circle)->where('id', $current_circle)->first();`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir This does seem shorter. I've already used above method, but  I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.